# Crontab error with php sendDiaryMail

Tags: centos, cron

I add the

```
30 22 * * * php /www/wwwroot/easy_xyz/xcat sendDiaryMail
```

line in my `crontab -e` to like this:

```
30 22 * * * php /www/wwwroot/easy_xyz/xcat sendDiaryMail
55 0 * * * "/root/.acme.sh"/acme.sh --cron --home "/root/.acme.sh" > /dev/null
```

but get error:

```
crontab: installing new crontab
"/tmp/crontab.d7MGaW":1: bad minute
errors in crontab file, can't install.
Do you want to retry the same edit?
```

where is the issue, I did not find it.

Comment: Maybe you write wrong character at the benning of line, open crontab again and check (this can happen if you copy and paste )

Comment: there is no wrong character.

Comment: Try removing the line and write it by your hand at the end of file and not copy / paste, you may see it more clear.

Comment: Avoid copy and pasting from web pages

Comment: Even copied & pasted out of your post the line gets happily used on my box?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
30 20 * * * /usr/bin/php /www/wwwroot/easy_xyz/xcat sendDiaryMail
```

Comment: this works, why?

Comment: Because the user running the cron job needs to have /usr/bin/php in their path.

Comment: the php have the path environment there, I think this is because of the other format, because I copy from the Mac text editor.

Answer (score 0):

Make very sure the `crontab` file is terminated with a  char.